# Evaluating the double integral of $|x+y|$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to evaluate this double integral:

$$
\iint_\Omega {\left| {x + y} \right|dxdy}, \quad \Omega  = \left\{ {(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :\left| x \right| < 1,\left| y \right| < 1} \right\}.
$$

Actually, this problems is listed in the section of Fubini's Theorem.

The question seems easy but I feel that miss something about the Theorem or the boundaries of integration.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

With symmetry we get that

$$\iint_\Omega |x+y|\:dxdy = 4\int_0^1 \int_{-x}^x x + y \: dy \:dx = \frac{8}{3}$$